# Auto Stretch Child Div to Parent and using % vs px margin/padding

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to make the child divs stretch to the parent and I'm not quite sure whether I need to specify % width on the #fullpage-content even though #middle is set to 76%??  I seem to have forgotten..

**[Here's a link](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/restaurants-pubs-and-bars/gastropubs/the-greyhound-brentwood-487.html) to the page where when clicking the on the buttons their respective containers aren't fitting the container.

Here's the main CSS:

```
#fullpage-content {clear:both;margin-top:1.5em;padding:10px 25px 30px;-webkit-border-radius:7px;-moz-border-radius:7px;border-radius:7px;border:px solid #e6e4e3;box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 4px #e0e0e0;background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f3f1f1), to(#fff));}

.Advert .tab {box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 4px #cac7c6;background:#fff;padding:5px 18px 15px;margin:0 0 8px 0;clear:left;float:left;-webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px;}

#contact {float:right;clear:right;width:220px;margin:15px 0 0 35px;}

.aboutus ul {list-style-image:url(/Assets/Images/SiteStructure/Advert-Template/bullet.gif);color:#4b4b4b;line-height:normal;padding-left:30px;}
.aboutus li  {padding:0 0 10px 5px;}
.abullets1, .abullets2 {float:left;width:30%;}
.bullets1, .bullets2  {width:33%;padding-left:20px;}
```

I also wondered if I needed to add position:relative to any of the container divs and specify fluid % margins/padding so it doesn't break?  Trying to get it working correctly...

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Block elements do not need `width: 100%`. They always take up as much horizontal space as they can.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the width of an element to 100% will make it the same width as its parent element. From what you have given i cannot quite tell what is what in your CSS but ill throw together a fiddle to show you.

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WgGfF/)

but yes if it is a div or block level element this is not needed as commented above